# Result after adding pagination code is getting messed up in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Below is a portion my code. I have created a text box and when the user enters a word/ phrase in the text box it searches the keyword in the database. This code also contains the code for pagination. 
The problem that I am facing in this code is that first time it displays the page number but at the first instance it doesn't displays the desired result. When I move from one page to another it loses the value from the variable "$each" and displays all results from the database. Whereas this code is supposed to display only the part of data which meets the criteria of the query

```
    <input type="text" name="k" 
        value="<?php if(isset($_GET['k'])){echo htmlentities($_GET['k']);} ?>" style="border: 1px, thin; width:92%; "/> 
    <input type="image" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 2px;" src="search.png"  value="submit" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tbody>    
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('', '', '');
if(!$connection)
    echo "No database connected";
$dbase = mysql_select_db("", $connection);
if(!$dbase)
    echo "No datatable connected";

if(isset($_GET['k'])){ 
    $k1 = $_GET['k']; 
} else { 
    $k1 = ''; 
}

echo $k1;

$term = explode(" ", $k1);

$query = "SELECT * FROM kcpdatabase ";

foreach ($term as $each) {
   echo $each;
    $i++;
   if($i==1) {
        $query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
   } else {
        $query .= "OR WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
}

echo $query;

$per_pages=3;
$page_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('title') FROM kcpdatabase");

$pages = ceil(mysql_result($page_query, 0)/$per_pages)  or die($page_query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); //Calculating the number of pages and round it to higher side

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) ($_GET['page']) : 1; //Checking wheather value of page is set or not. 
                                                         //If not then assign it as a default value of 1.
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_pages; // Point to the record zero always to start displaying the data

$query .= "LIMIT $start, $per_pages";

$ourquery1 = mysql_query ($query);
if(!$ourquery1)
    echo "No query found";

    $row1 = mysql_num_rows ($ourquery1);

if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){ 
   for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++) {
        echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
   }

    if ($row1 > 0) {

        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ourquery1)) {
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            $title = $result['title'];
            $link = $result['link'];
            $region = $result['region'];
            $sector = $result['sector'];
            $theme = $result['theme'];      
            echo "<td> <a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";
            echo "<h4>Sector: $sector Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
            <br> Region: $region </td> </tr>";
        }
    }   
}
echo "</tbody>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your search criteria to your pagination links (`k=$k1`), as it is currently only being set when you submit the form. Try something like -

```
if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){ 
   for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++) {
        echo '<a href="?k='.$k1.'&page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
   }
```

note- you are currently using unsanitized user input in `$k1` => `$each`.

Answer (score 0):

[Please, don't use mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about *[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)* instead, and use **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo)** or **[MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)** - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo)**, [here is a good tutorial.](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2)

Comment: Although this is great information, this should be a comment, not an answer, as it does nothing to help solve the OP's question.